# SSMS print on same screen on while loop

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a basic select script should be running every 3 seconds and print out results on SSMS.

But during while loop, this script prints results on different views (keeps creating vertical separated tabs).

Is there any way to clear historical results and only keep latest select output?

```
while 1=1
begin
select top 100 DATEDIFF(minute, datecreated, getdate()) minutesAgo, exception, exceptionmessage, * 
from Exceptions 
order by exceptionid desc
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
end
```

Comment: You could try: https://www.mssqltips.com/tipimages2/2346_image004.png. But I guess it will open pane for every new execution.

Comment: Yeah, this is a kind of odd layout for me:) Thanks for hint though.